# Eclipse plugin does not find artifacts in local maven repo

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I have a multi module maven project, which builds fine on the command line. When I import the project into eclipse, it complains, that *some* dependencies cannot be resolved. Most dependencies do get resovled just fine.

I'm getting this error messgae for some dependencies:

```
Missing artifact com.visual-paradigm.hibernate:orm:jar:20140430 pom.xml /lir    line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
```

I checked the eclipse maven config and I can see that the dependencies are actually in the local repo.

Any ideas how to get eclipse/maven to resolve this dependencies?

Comment: are you using m2eclipse or the mvn eclipse:eclipse. The latter needs an M2_HOME variable, I believe

Comment: What is the exact error message? Do you get the same error from the command line? What happens when you use Run As -> Maven install?

Comment: I'm using the m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can try updating settings.xml to be used by plugin.

[image]

Also try updating maven instance eclipse is using.

**Edit 1**
In eclipse .classpath file see if the entry is present for given jar. I believe there should be entries for other jars as you have mentioned in eclipse. 
like this

```
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
```

Now there can be 2 cases with it

1. classpath entry is present and somehow jar is not located on specified path.
2. classpath entry is absent, if not a quick fix would be manually adding it.

Comment: As state, I have alredy checked the settings. Everything looks fine.

Comment: check .classpath maybe that can help updated answer to include it

Answer (score 0):

After all it turned out, that the missing dependencies were added to the repo using copy paste instead of using `install:install-file`. Therefore some meta information in the repo was missing.

Deleting them and readding with `install:install-file` solved the problem.

What's still puzzling is that on the command line maven was happy with this. Even kicking off maven install from eclipse was working fine. It's just the m2eclipse plugin that has a problem with this.